# How to find the intersection of the normal CDF and the `y = x` line?

Tags: normal-distribution

The normal distribution does not have a closed form cdf (per [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_distribution)). Is there a way to find its intersection with the line `x = y`?

Currently I use statistical software (`R`) to search through a fine grid of `x`'s until I find an `x` value such that $\Phi(x) = x$. Is there a better way, either solving it analytically or computationally but takes less time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It exists a nice approximation formula for the cdf:

$$\large{\Phi (x) \approx  0.5 \cdot \Bigg( 1 + \sqrt{1-e^{- \left(\sqrt{\frac{\pi}{8}} \cdot x^2\right)}} \Bigg)}=x$$

This equation can not solved algebraically. But you can apply an approximation method, for instance the Newton-Raphson method. [Wolfram alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=0.5+%2B0.5*%28sqrt%281-e%5E%28-+%28sqrt%28pi%2F8%29*x%5E2%29%29%29%29%3Dx) calculated the value $x=0.78215$. And $\Phi (0.78215)=0.78294$

The exact value, with 5 decimal places, is $0.78326$

The article where the formula is mentioned can be found [here](http://www.m-hikari.com/ams/ams-password-2008/ams-password9-12-2008/alodatAMS9-12-2008-2.pdf). It is the journal *Applied Mathematical Sciences*, Vol. 2, 2008, no. 9, 425 - 429

Comment: Could you explain or may be add a source about how this approximation is derived?

Comment: @Heisenberg I have added the source. See the edit.